# Fetch previous month from the date entered in where clause in query in DB2

Tags: db2

I would like to know if there is a way to fetch last previous month record? For example if the below query is ran then the query should provide output for transactions between 01-04-2019 until 30-04-2019 ( 1st april to 30th april).

`select * from table where transdate>='01-01-2019' and transdate <='31-05-2019'
Sample data 
TRANSDATE   LABOR     Hours
01-01-2019     A       2.5
23-01-2019     B       1.0
01-02-2019     B       3.0
12-03-2019     A       0.5
02-04-2019     A       1.5
12-04-2019     B       4.5
17-04-2019     B       2.0
22-04-2019     C       2.5
12-05-2019     A       3.5
Expected Output 
TRANSDATE   LABOR     Hours
Apr-2019       A       1.5
Apr-2019       B       6.5
Apr-2019       C       2.5`

Comment: Your question is asking for a single month of data, but your `WHERE` clause is asking for all of January through May inclusive.  Which one do you actually want?

Comment: Yes user would enter dates for 3 months or 6 months but there is one section where the data should display only single month data hence I wanted to know if this is possible.

Comment: @max092012 Please, provide an example of data and the result needed.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein edited my question with sample data.

Comment: @max092012 How to get the value of `last previous month`? What’s the base of such a calculation? Is this max `translate` in the result set for given condition in the `where` clause? Some other logic like based on a user provided input (`31-05-2019`)?

Comment: Side note: Absolutely do not use an inclusive upper-bound (`<=`) for date/time types, especially when dealing with "end of the month".  You will find it _far_ easier to say "less than the start of the next month" - that is, an exclusive upper-bound (`<`) - you'd be surprised how many people forget leap days...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `last previous month` is calculated based on user input (`2019-05-31`, for example), then:

```
select to_char(TRANSDATE, 'Mon-YYYY', 'en-US') as TRANSDATE, LABOR, sum(Hours) as Hours
from table
where transdate between 
    date('2019-05-31') - (day(date('2019-05-31')) - 1) days - 1 month
and date('2019-05-31') - day(date('2019-05-31')) days
group by to_char(TRANSDATE, 'Mon-YYYY', 'en-US'), LABOR
;
```

User can provide any date of month. The result of the expressions in the `between` clause is the same for any provided date of the same month.

Comment: Please don't use `BETWEEN` (or more specifically, an inclusive upper-bound) for date/time types.  It's better to use an exclusive upper-bound.